# XCode Instruments - Show taps on screen

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I have just started using XCode Instruments and I'm doing some UI automation. To make life a bit easier I would like some kind of indication on the screen where I am tapping.

Does Instruments have an API call that will display the current location of a tap?

Comment: After much testing it seems Instruments isn't something that would be great for many applications on iOS. No delay tracking between apps as well as a lack of proper key logging. 

Such a shame as this would be great if it was developed seriously.